# Parcable of generic array

Tags: android, generics, parcelable

I generate parcelable implementation with plugin and that is the code i got.
I have a an error compilation on  `Metrics(Parcel in)`.
It probably because the generic array. How can i fix it?
The generic T can can contain String, Number or boolean only.

```
public class Metrics<T extends Parcelable> implements Parcelable {
    private T[] yData;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeTypedArray(this.yData, flags);
    }

    public Metrics() {
    }

    protected Metrics(Parcel in) {
        this.yData = in.createTypedArray(T.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Metrics> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Metrics>() {
        @Override
        public Metrics createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Metrics(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Metrics[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Metrics[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `List` instead of an array :

```
public class Metrics<T extends Parcelable> implements Parcelable {

    private List<T> yData;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        if (yData == null || yData.size() == 0)
            dest.writeInt(0);
        else {
            dest.writeInt(yData.size());
            final Class<?> objectsType = yData.get(0).getClass();
            dest.writeSerializable(objectsType);
            dest.writeList(yData);
        }
    }

    public Metrics() {
    }

    protected Metrics(Parcel in) {

        int size = in.readInt();
        if (size == 0) {
            yData = null;
        } else {
            Class<?> type = (Class<?>) in.readSerializable();
            yData = new ArrayList<>(size);
            in.readList(yData, type.getClassLoader());
        }
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Metrics> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Metrics>() {
        @Override
        public Metrics createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Metrics(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Metrics[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Metrics[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: I know but i would like the array. Is it possible with array? or the only way is list?